# How do I uninstall Microsoft edge?

Tags: uninstall, deb

I just install Microsoft Edge browser using a deb package.

Now I can not uninstall it.

If I go to the menu, and right click on it, there is no option to uninstall.

If I open Discover app, Edge it not listed anywhere, I did an exhaustive search...

Comment: If you use a package manager, it will likely see it and allow removal without using command (given you mention `discover` it maybe `muon` that your system has, being used by Lubuntu/Kubuntu that both come with `discover`; but `synaptic`, `aptitude` and others may also offer removal via their UI)

Comment: cant find it in muon or apt eithe. When I used Linux mint I could easily uninstall anything installed by deb.

Answer (score 16):

To remove the stable version, run

```
sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-stable
```

And for the beta version,

```
sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-beta
```

---

**Previous version of the asnwer.**

The name of the package is `microsoft-edge-dev` according to [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/10/microsoft-edge-dev-available-install-ubuntu/) link.

To remove it, enter the command

```
sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-dev
```

To remove the settings and configuration files along with the program, enter the command

```
sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-dev
```

Comment: sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-beta if you have beta version.

Comment: sudo apt remove microsoft-edge-stable if you have the stable version